# How to get location - php

Tags: javascript, php, location, ip

I want to get the location of a client on my webpage.

I can do it with either PHP or Javascript.

I'm currently trying to get the location by the client's IP address and by using geoip extension for PHP.

But it requires a datgabase and I don't want that.

Is there any other way to find the client's location?

Comment: did any of the anwsers help you? please mark them accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://ipinfo.io/ which is a third-party database.

That database doesn't require any addons so it's easy to use with PHP.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // get client's IP
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));// Send to ipinfo
echo $details->city; // Gives you the city of the client.
echo $details->country; // Gives you the country of the client.
```

EDIT: I also saw you added a javascript tag, you can do this with jQuery aswell.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get latitude and longitude using javascript.

```
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}

function showError(error) {
switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
        break;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: And with lat and long, you can perform a reverse search usin Google API and get the city